# Stringify a JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a JSON column in a table. i.e 
**table**

```
    column
---------------
[2,5,7,21,1,54,12]
```

Now its returning array for the below query.

```
select column from table
```

**Output**
   => [2,5,7,21,1,54,12]

What I want is Output as "*2,5,7,21,1,54,12*".

Any suggestion?

Comment: Normalize your database. What's the point storing such serialized datas ?

Comment: You can use nested `replace()` functions to remove the `[` and `]`  or you can use a comination of `SUBSTRING()` and `LENGTH()`, see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuTqsTB2C3ePqJsjXdR8TP/1) , there should be more MySQL [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) which can do the same.

Comment: @Cid this is for reporting purpose. I need to get it as stringify format. Whereas when the data gets inserted It needs to be in JSON array format.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Yes thats the last option I can think.. There is no JSON function  to join the array elements?

Comment: *"I need to get it as stringify format. Whereas when the data gets inserted It needs to be in JSON array format"* JSON array format is always with `[]` and also it sounds very contradictory with *"What I want is Output as "2,5,7,21,1,54,12"."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a sample of querying a JSON array:

```
select data from t;
+--------------------------+
| data                     |
+--------------------------+
| [2, 5, 7, 21, 1, 54, 12] |
+--------------------------+
```

You can turn a JSON array into a string using [JSON_UNQUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote). But it formats the string with square brackets and spaces:

```
select json_unquote(data) as stringified from t;
+--------------------------+
| stringified              |
+--------------------------+
| [2, 5, 7, 21, 1, 54, 12] |
+--------------------------+
```

You can remove those unwanted characters with [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
select replace(replace(replace(json_unquote(data), ' ', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') as stringified from t;
+------------------+
| stringified      |
+------------------+
| 2,5,7,21,1,54,12 |
+------------------+
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can replace the characters in one call to [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
select regexp_replace(json_unquote(data), '[\\[\\] ]', '') as stringified from t;
+------------------+
| stringified      |
+------------------+
| 2,5,7,21,1,54,12 |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution is to use `JSON_TABLE()` and MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` capabilities.

With such a data sample :

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user   | emails (JSON)                                                      |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user-1 | ["user-1@email-1.net", "user-1@email-2.net", "user-1@email-3.net"] |
| user-2 | ["user-2@email-1.net"]                                             |
| user-3 | ["user-3@email-1.net", "user-3@email-2.net"]                       |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to output :

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| user   | emails (TEXT)                                                  |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| user-1 | user-1@email-1.net // user-1@email-2.net // user-1@email-3.net |
| user-2 | user-2@email-1.net                                             |
| user-3 | user-3@email-1.net // user-3@email-2.net"                      |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We can do :

```
WITH data_sample (user, emails) AS (
  -- Fake data build to test query
  VALUES 
    ROW ('user-1', JSON_ARRAY('user-1@email-1.net', 'user-1@email-2.net', 'user-1@email-3.net')),
    ROW ('user-2', JSON_ARRAY('user-2@email-1.net')),
    ROW ('user-3', JSON_ARRAY('user-3@email-1.net', 'user-3@email-2.net'))
)
SELECT ALL user, GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ' // ') AS emails
FROM data_sample
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(emails, '$[*]' COLUMNS (email TINYTEXT PATH '$')) AS _
GROUP BY user;
```